# Scrapy Crawling 0 pages

Tags: python, html, scrapy

New to python and scrapy, whats wrong with the code? I can retrieve the data from scrapy shell but why cannot retrieve in scrapy crawl?

EDIT: I have put the log at below, could you help me check what problem it is?

Problem SOLVED:
 
This link is incorrect ?price=2-2/
Should be ?price=2-2

**quotes.spider.py**

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://www.testing.com.my/?price=2-2/',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "c-product-card__img-placeholder-inner")]/@href')
    return titles.extract()
```

**items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class TutorialItem(Item):
    link = Field()
```

**Log**

```
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: tutorial
)
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': '
tutorial', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPID
ER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pag
es/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-07-05 16:26:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening o
n 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-07-05 16:26:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.la
zada.com.my/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-07-05 16:26:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.la
zada.com.my/shop-power-banks2/?price=2-2/> (referer: None)
2017-07-05 16:26:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-07-05 16:26:55 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 596,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 55953,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 5, 8, 26, 55, 942385),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 5, 8, 26, 52, 624796)}
2017-07-05 16:26:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Is it a problem of indentation ? definition of methods on same level as the class definition

Comment: Can you share your `scrapy crawl` logs?

Comment: @Pablo the indentation should not be the problem on my side, i copy & paste it here but the alignment have some problem, so I manually indent it

Comment: I think the selector is wrong and didnt't get anything, that's why you don't get any output. i tried on the website but the class name of the link doesn't return anything. What are you trying to extract ?

Comment: @Pablo yes, I'm trying to extract, i will edit what I want to extract

Comment: Sry everyone who was trying, i found out the link should be  
http://www.lazada.com.my/shop-power-banks2/?price=2-2 not http://www.lazada.com.my/shop-power-banks2/?price=2-2/

Comment: I have solve the problem, thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract the link for each article, i'd propose something like :

```
response.css("a.c-product-card::attr(href)")
```

instead of :

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "c-product-card__img-placeholder-inner")]/@href')
```

Comment: Great alternative, anyway I have solve the previous problem, thanks for helping me